# trying to display div when user hovers over an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of images displayed, when the user hovers over them I want a small transparent div with image description displaying. Only when hovered.

The Attempt: The description div `.widget_sp_image-description` is displayed none an when the user hovers it is displayed to block with `position: absolute`.

The problem: Nothing is happening when hovering over the image. What am I doing wrong here, ideas?

HTML

```
<section id="widget_sp_image-7" class="widget widget_sp_image">
<img width="735" height="426" class="attachment-735x426" style="max-width: 100%;" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/project1-1.jpg">
<div class="widget_sp_image-description">
    <p>Company Name: ELES AINC<br>
            Objective: Blah las lkajsd lkjsad lkasdjalk asdlk jkj  ljsdaj llasdlkj laksdjas lkajsd la ljskda lakjsd kjks k jkjkjkjk lkjsdks.<br>
            Project Cycke: 2012- 2014</p>
</div>
```

css

```
/* Image Widget Images Container */
.widget_sp_image {
    position: relative;
}
.widget_sp_image-description {
    display: none;
 }

.widget_sp_image-description:hover {
    display: block;

    background-color:rgba(251, 194, 40, 0.54);
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 426px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the `div` when you hover the corresponding `image` use the following code:

```
.widget_sp_image:hover .widget_sp_image-description
```

*Why did your code not work?*

You used the following code: `.widget_sp_image-description:hover` It would show the div when you hover over the div itself, but when the div is not displayed, then you can't ofc hover it.

**Working demo**

```css
.widget_sp_image {
  position: relative;
}

.widget_sp_image-description {
  display: none;
}

.widget_sp_image:hover .widget_sp_image-description {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(251, 194, 40, 0.54);
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 426px;
}
```

```html
<section id="widget_sp_image-7" class="widget widget_sp_image">
  <img width="735" height="426" class="attachment-735x426" style="max-width: 100%;" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/project1-1.jpg">
  <div class="widget_sp_image-description">
    <p>Company Name: ELES AINC<br> Objective: Blah las lkajsd lkjsad lkasdjalk asdlk jkj ljsdaj llasdlkj laksdjas lkajsd la ljskda lakjsd kjks k jkjkjkjk lkjsdks.<br> Project Cycke: 2012- 2014</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="widget_sp_image-7" class="widget widget_sp_image">
  <img width="735" height="426" class="attachment-735x426" style="max-width: 100%;" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/project1-1.jpg">
  <div class="widget_sp_image-description">
    <p>Company Name: ELES AINC<br> Objective: Blah las lkajsd lkjsad lkasdjalk asdlk jkj ljsdaj llasdlkj laksdjas lkajsd la ljskda lakjsd kjks k jkjkjkjk lkjsdks.<br> Project Cycke: 2012- 2014</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Boom! it Worked!

Comment: You're definitely smashing it on stack overflow, solid rep points ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please first of assign div which you want to show and than add that div class after **.widget_sp_image:hover**

Like that :

```
.widget_sp_image:hover .widget_sp_image-description {....}
```

and than add css **display: block;**

```css
.widget_sp_image {
  position: relative;
}
.widget_sp_image-description {
  display: none;
}

.widget_sp_image:hover .widget_sp_image-description {
  display: block;
  
  
  background-color: rgba(251, 194, 40, 0.54);
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 426px;
}
```

```html
<section id="widget_sp_image-7" class="widget widget_sp_image">
  <img width="735" height="426" class="attachment-735x426" style="max-width: 100%;" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/project1-1.jpg">
  <div class="widget_sp_image-description">
    <p>Company Name: ELES AINC<br> Objective: Blah las lkajsd lkjsad lkasdjalk asdlk jkj ljsdaj llasdlkj laksdjas lkajsd la ljskda lakjsd kjks k jkjkjkjk lkjsdks.<br> Project Cycke: 2012- 2014</p>
  </div>
</section>
```